# Resizing for 3.5 and 4inch screen

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, constraints, autoresize

wondering if anyone can help, I've always struggled with resizing for both screen sizes.? What is the best way to do it?
At the moment with the 4 inch screen all my layout is perfect then when I view it in the 3.5 inch screen it cuts off some icons at the bottom of the screen? How do I resolve this? Any know of any good videos to teach you with layouts etc? Thanks..

Comment: Have you look at here ? : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: define "best way". For an end user, they look for a layout that perfectly fits their layout.

Comment: Well is it better to use autolayout? Or constraints? Do you set it all up whilst in then 4 inch view? I just can never get it to look the same in both sizes?

Comment: you are make design for 3.5 inch screen and then resize for 4 inch screen.

Comment: als o use autolayout for this

Comment: Ok so I've set everything up on the 3.5inch screen.. I have everything at the top sorted so when the screen is bigger it stops in the same place, problem is I have three icons at the bottom of the screen how do I tell them to go down with the toolbar as there is a big space at the bottom when display 4inch screen. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

select `NewFile` > `UserInterferance` >`view` (new xib file )connect FileOwner with ViewController and set the size of interference builder .you can choose with Retina3.5 Full Screen or Retina 4 Full Screen ..